# kafka 0.10.1.1 stops responding sporadically

Tags: apache-kafka

We use kafka 0.10.1.1 and it is running fine for few hours and sometimes few days. All of sudden it starts giving the below exception and broker loses connection between them. The zookeeper and kafka server processes are running, but not accepting any connection.

We are running kafka and zookeeper on the same node and its a 2 nodes cluster setup. This is just our dev environment.

The below exception was observed in the server log.

```
2017-03-23 14:05:52,729] WARN [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-38], Error in fetch kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread$FetchRequest@1893e027 (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to 2 was disconnected before the response was read
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$$anonfun$blockingSendAndReceive$extension$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:115)
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$$anonfun$blockingSendAndReceive$extension$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:112)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$$anonfun$blockingSendAndReceive$extension$1.apply(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:112)
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$$anonfun$blockingSendAndReceive$extension$1.apply(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:108)
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.recursivePoll$1(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:137)
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.kafka$utils$NetworkClientBlockingOps$$pollContinuously$extension(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:143)
        at kafka.utils.NetworkClientBlockingOps$.blockingSendAndReceive$extension(NetworkClientBlockingOps.scala:108)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.sendRequest(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:253)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetch(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:238)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetch(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:42)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.processFetchRequest(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:118)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:103)
```

From Zookeeper.log,

```
[2017-03-22 22:42:15,600] INFO Client attempting to establish new session at /10.141.202.141:59930 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-03-22 22:42:15,603] INFO Established session 0x25af82f142c0000 with negotiated timeout 6000 for client /11.121.102.441:59930 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-03-22 22:42:29,322] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x25af82f142c0000 type:create cxid:0x3a8 zxid:0x1e0000001a txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2017-03-22 22:42:29,329] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x25af82f142c0000 type:create cxid:0x3a9 zxid:0x1e0000001b txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/ids Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers/ids (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2017-03-22 22:42:32,943] INFO Accepted socket connection from /17.150.218.7:58233 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2017-03-22 22:42:32,944] WARN Connection request from old client /17.150.218.7:58233; will be dropped if server is in r-o mode (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-03-22 22:42:32,944] INFO Client attempting to establish new session at /17.150.218.7:58233 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-03-22 22:42:32,947] INFO Established session 0x25af82f142c0001 with negotiated timeout 30000 for client /17.121.102.241:58233 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-03-22 22:42:33,402] INFO Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x25af82f142c0001 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2017-03-22 22:42:33,405] INFO Closed socket connection for client /17.150.218.7:58233 which had sessionid 0x25af82f142c0001 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
```

Thanks

Comment: Any news? This happened to us in production. Pretty bad.

Comment: We are still facing this issue in our 2 nodes cluster. But, looks like 3 nodes cluster is fine. But, we are yet to move all our customers from our 2 node cluster to our 3 nodes cluster.

Comment: we see the same issue on Kafka 0.11, with 5 brokers, on AWS ....

Comment: Do you have any custom code like custom Authorizer or Authenticator?

Comment: How did you guys cope with this issue? Was it identified/tracked/fixed in JIRA? What were the consequences in your case? Thanks for sharing!